# Changing route back and forth and subscription callbacks

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular2 beta 17 version. I have found out, that when I have a longer request to the server (2-3s), and I switch the routes couple of time (back and forth), the callback gets executed the number of times the route has changed. I solved this by adding `.unsubscribe()` in `ngOnDestroy`. However, shouldn't this be done by default on http calls when changing the router? Has this been fixed in latest RC?

Comment: The router doesn't know about http calls. I don't think this is or will be implemented.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, don't you think that this should be implemented though? This may cause a lots of problem, and unsubscribing from each http call is painful. Can you use your connections :)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have connections that would help here. I don't think this would be a valuable feature. If a resource is requested imperatively, then it should be freed imperatively. What if you make a call on a shared service and you don't want to cancel the request when you navigate away?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, that is correct. However, restricting this to canceling callbacks coming from components used in router - that, in my opinion, would be pretty nice.

Comment: How should the router know the request was made from a component? IMHO that is way to fragile and doesn't carry its weight and would cause more problems than it fixes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I guess you made a good point.